# Should I use map or switchmap when using angular http module?

Tags: rxjs, switchmap

I use the following code in an angular app. I used the RxJS `map` call similar to how array `map` is used. After reading about RxJS `switchmap` operator, I'm not sure whether I should use `map` or `switchmap`. Should I use `switchmap` so the observable which is returned from the `http` call is closed so there is no memory leak?

```
getPeopleForTypeahead(term: string): Observable<IPersonForTypeahead[]> {

    var peopleUrl = `https://localhost:5001/api/peoplesearch?name=${term}`;

    return this.http.get<any>(peopleUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(pl => {
          return this.peopleAsFlattened(pl.peopleList).reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c));
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPeopleForTypeahead', []))
      );
  }

  peopleAsFlattened = (pla: IPeopleList[]) => {
    return pla.map(pl => pl.people.map(p => {
      return {
        id: p.id,
        fullName: p.fullNames[0].firstName + " " + p.fullNames[0].lastName
      };
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` and `switchMap` have completely different purposes:

- `map` - transform the shape of an emission
- `switchMap` - subscribe to an observable and emit its emissions into the stream

---

### `map`

Use `map` when you want transform the shape of each emission. Ex: emit the user name property, instead of the entire user object:

```js
userName$: Observable<string> = this.service.getUser(123).pipe(
    map(user => user.name)
);
```

### `switchMap`

Use `switchMap` when you want to map an emission to another observable and emit its emissions.  Ex: You have an observable of some `id` and want to emit the resource after fetching it:

```js
user$: Observable<User> = this.userId$.pipe(
  switchMap(id => this.service.getUser(id)),
);
```

When `user$` is subscribed to, the user returned from `service.getUser(id)` is emitted (*not the userId string*).

Comment: In this example, is `userId$` called outer observable and whatever observable returned by the `switchMap` called inner observable?

Comment: Can't the `map` method also return `this.service.getUser(id)` like the `switchMap` does?

Comment: Yes, you are correct about terms inner observable and outer observable.  As for having `map` return `this.service.getUser()`, you could do that however, `map` will emit the observable, where as `switchMap` will internally subscribe to the inner observable and emit the emissions from the inner observable.  Usually it's not helpful to emit an observable, you usually want the value from the inner observable.

Comment: Don't both scenarios emit `Observable<user>` which can be subscribed? Or the first scenario return `Observable<Observable<<user>>` and the second scenario `Observable<user>`?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-map-vs-switchmap-bb?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts

Comment: Nope, check out the above example stackblitz which shows the emission types for map vs switchMap.

Comment: You may find this article about "[Higher Order Mapping Operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`switchMap` is not interchangeable with the `map` operator, nor vise versa. Although both of them has to do with mapping (as their names suggest), they have two separate use-cases.

In your particular case, the `map` operator is the way to go.

#### When to use `switchMap`?

You can only use `switchMap(cb)` when you check all these requirements:

1. Your callback function, `cb`,  passed into `switchMap` returns an observable, `observable$`.

   If your `cb` (callback function) does not return an observable, you should look into operators that don't handle higher-level observables, such as `filter` and `map` (what you actually needed); **not** operators that handle higher-level observables such as `concatMap` and well, `switchMap`.
2. You want to execute your `cb` sequentially before the next operation down the pipeline (after `switchMap`) executes.

   Maybe you want to run logic inside of `cb`, and optionally get the return value of `cb` after executing, so that you can pass it down the pipeline for further processing, for example.
3. When you want to "discard" what will happen to `cb`'s execution and re-execute `cb` every time the source observable (the thing that trickles down to `switchMap(cb)`) emits a new value/notification.

---

Applying what we hopefully learned, we know that your `cb`:

```js
pl => {
    return this.peopleAsFlattened(pl.peopleList).reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c));
}
```

returns a plain JavaScript array; not an observable. This takes using `switchMap` out of the question since it violates the first requirement I made up above.

Hopefully that makes sense. :)

Comment: The method `getPeopleForTypeahead(term: string)` returns `Observable<IPersonForTypeahead[]>` and not an array.

Comment: Right, but it's not about what `getPeopleForYpeahead()` returns. It's about what what your callback `pl => { ... }` returns.

Answer (score 0):

We use `switchMap` when the source observable is a hot observable. In which case you prefer the behaviour that cancel the succeeding observable when source emits.

In your code, you source is a one-off http call which means it will not emit multiple times and the follow up action is not executing observable but to mutate an array.  There is no need to use `switchMap`